# Spring Security logged user

Tags: spring-security

I'm using Spring Security and I need to redirect to another page each time a logged user accesses a particular page.

I tried testing SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME variable and using response.sendRedirect("newpage.htm") to redirect, but this does not ensure that the user is logged in. how could i do this?

Comment: The problem is already solved, I tested SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT variable and it works fine.